# Create an Item/Project Template in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to figure out how to create an Item Template but according to the online articles I've encountered so far, all of the articles point you to an Export Template Wizard tool under the File menu option.  My problem is that this feature doesn't exist and I can't seem to find it.

I'm using Visual Studio Team System 2008.

So I'm wondering a couple of things.  Does VSTS 2008 not include this option intentionally?  Or do you go about creating Item/Project templates in a different manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of the steps above mentions clicking on the 'Export Template' option of the File menu, but you may not initially see it there. In that case:
>
> - Right-click the menu bar and choose 'Customize....'
>
>   - Click on the File category and then 'Rearrange Commands'
>   - Click the 'Add...' button, then click the 'File' category in the dialogue that pops up
>   - Scroll down until you see 'Export Template...', then highlight that and click OK.
>   - Use the Move Up/Down buttons to place it where you want
>   - Click 'Close' a couple times
>
> Now you have 'Export Template' available and can follow the steps above!

*Source:* [MSDN: How to create Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using VS 2010 you can do lot more...You can get the complete example implemented here: [Multi-Project Templates with Wizard: Visual Studio 2010 Sample](http://vsix.codeplex.com/)